# How to filter CAN messages in Autosar?

Tags: can-bus, autosar, pdu, uds

I am new to `AUTOSAR` com module. I would like to perform some scenario to check specific messages in CAN FD. Here I want to block all the `CAN FD` messages except one message (`eg: ID: 0x22`) during some event occurred.

My idea is to loop all the `CAN FD` `PDU` ID's and check the corresponding message ID(`0x22`). Here the problem is, I have to traverse through all the `CAN FD` `PDU` ID's. (If CAN FD PDU's are `200`, I have to loop `200` times.)

I would like to know, Is there any other good method to block all the `CAN FD` message except some messages in AUTOSAR environment? Also where i have to block this PDU's ? Is it in `COM` module or `CANIf` module ? Please correct me if my understandings are wrong.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? What do you want to block Rx or Tx PDUs? If Tx, you could maybe group the Tx PDUs into a separate IPduGroup and turn that group on/off on the event. The ISignalIPdus (handled in Com) have the trigger condition to send the Frame they are mapped to. You can trigger the IpduGroups change on conditions in BswM

Comment: @kesselhaus In my case, ECU is transmitting (Tx) all the messages during on event. I want block all the transmitted messages except some messages. I want know how can i filter those messages? If i am grouping all the Tx PDUs in to one, I have to filter the corresponding messages with PDU ID. In Autosar or COM module, how can i block specific messages ?

Comment: @kesselhaus In Autosar or COM module, how can i block specific messages inside a PDU Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create several Tx ISignalIPduGroups in the SystemDescription/EcuExtract. You assign each ISignalIpdu to the according ISignalIPduGroup. Then you can enable/disable the necessary ISignalIPduGroup.

e.g.

```
IPduGroup_Tx_A - CommunicationDirection=OUT
    ISignalIPdu_Tx1
    ISignalIPdu_Tx2
IPduGroup_Tx_B - CommunicationDirection=OUT
    ISignalIPdu_Tx3
    ISignalIPdu_Tx4

IPduGroup_Rx_B - CommunicationDirection=IN
    ISignalIPdu_Rx1
    ISignalIPdu_Rx2
IPduGroup_Rx_B - CommunicationDirection=IN
    ISignalIPdu_Rx3
    ISignalIPdu_Rx4
```

You can either trigger it directly over Com

```
void MyCdd_MainFunction(void)
{
    if (cond_tx_a == TRUE) {
        Com_IpduGroupStart(COM_IPDUGROUP_TX_A, TRUE);
    } else {
        Com_IpduGroupStop(COM_IPDUGROUP_TX_A);
    }
    if (cond_tx_b == TRUE) {
        Com_IPduGroupStart(COM_IPDUGROUP_TX_B, TRUE);
    } else {
        Com_IpduGroupStop(COM_IPDUGROUP_TX_B);
    }
    
    if (cond_rx_a == TRUE) {
        Com_IpduGroupStart(COM_IPDUGROUP_RX_A, TRUE);
    } else {
        Com_IpduGroupStop(COM_IPDUGROUP_RX_A);
    }
    if (cond_rx_b == TRUE) {
        Com_IPduGroupStart(COM_IPDUGROUP_RX_B, TRUE);
    } else {
        Com_IpduGroupStop(COM_IPDUGROUP_RX_B);
    }
}
```

So, when `cond_tx_a == TRUE` it will start the `IPduGroup_TX_A` and therefore, the `ISignalIPdu_Tx1` and `ISignalIPdu_Tx2` will be transmitted now, but `ISignalIPdu_Tx1` and `ISignalIPdu_Tx2` will not be sent, unless `cond_tx_b == TRUE`. The same is happening with the `IPduGroup_RX_A` and `IPduGroup_RX_B` and their mapped ISignalIPdus, except, for Rx PDUs, you actually disable to the reception, but actually the Deadline Monitoring of Rx ISignalIPdus.

You could also configure such switching of IPduGroups in BswM (see configuration `BswMPduGroupSwitch`) without much writing direct code.

We had this with some OEM, where all messages had a assignment to a PowerSource, if transmitted or not.

```
IpduGroup_PowerSource_PlusB
IpduGroup_PowerSource_ACC
IPduGroup_PowerSource_IG1
IPduGroup_PowerSource_IG2
```

We had some rules generated out of the NetworkDescription, which automatically start/stop the Ipdus depending on, if they are mapped to the group or not. PowerStatus was the input to the BswM. BswM even has now BswMTimer support. So you could e.g. make rules, to:

- start a BswMTimer_IG1 with a timeout of 3000ms.
- after the BswMTImer_IG1 elapsed, that is another input to actually switch the Rx-IpduGroup on, in order to start the timeout monitoring in Com for the mapped PDUs only 3000ms after IG-ON. That is usually some settling time, where all the ECUs in the vehicle wakeup/start (Clamp15), and not all messages are all yet available on bus, and would cause Timeout DTCs to be logged.

The nice thing about BswM is, it is mostly configured, without actually writing one line of code manually.
You could even update this in case of POSTBUILD configurations.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. your efforts appreciated !!